# Make two Java file separate from each other in one folder

Tags: java

I usually do my homework on a Java file and submit the file to complete my task, so I separate each file and contain them all in one folder. Sometimes there are two works that have the same class name, but different work. If I let two files have the same class name, they won't run properly. (I'm using vscode)

For example:

File1.java

```
public class File1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ...        
    }
}
class Fraction {...}
```

File2.java

```
public class File2{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ...        
    }
}
class Fraction {...} //this is not the same with File1.java
```

Can I do anything keep two class names the same in two different files in one folder?

Comment: 'Sometimes there are 2 works that have the same class name': that's the problem. Solution: don't. You can't rationally expect to have two files with the same name.

Comment: When you just run them (JDK 11 or newer), using `java File1.java` or `java File2.java`, no class files will be stored on disc and there’s no clash. However, when you submit your homework, you’re dependent on how your teacher will run the code.

Answer (score -2):

Do not define the same class name (whether the same script or not) in the same folder. This throws an error many times.

Comment: It doesn't 'throw' any errors at all. It just overwrites the older one with the newer one.

Answer (score -2):

Largely all filenames are Operating System rules dependent.
Java source code files must be named by the main class name of the code in the file. After compiling, a file of the same name but different extension, extension of .class will be there. Dependent how the compiler command line flags are set it will simply by default overwrite any old version .class file.
type **javac -h** on the shell or prompt for compile command flags info.

Comment: That's not what the question is about.